# What's an example of a non-admissible coordinate change for a tensor T?

Tags: tensors

Suppose I have a tensor T, they always say that T has an "admissible" change of coordinate systems as:

$\mathcal{T} : \bar{x}^i = \bar{x}^i(x^1, x^2, \dots, x^n)$

But, what would be an example of an "un-admissible" change of coordinate systems?

In other words, is there an example of a transform $\mathcal{T}$ that is un-admissible so that tensor T does not obey the transformation laws $\bar{T}^i =  T_r J^i_r$?

Answer (score 0):

If the transform $\mathcal{T}$ is not bijective, then, this is an un-admissible change of coordinates.  (bijective means that we have a one-to-one mapping of coordinates from the "$x^i$ system" to the "$\bar{x}^i$ system")

However, many non-bijective functions are bijection on a restricted region, thus, a transform that is un-admissible maybe be admissible on a range of coordinate values.  For example, restricting the angle coordinate $\theta$ of a polar coordinate system between the ranges $\pi$ and $-\pi$ will convert the transform $\mathcal{T}$ from an un-admissible change of coordinates to an admissible  change of coordinates.